# Filter date results by adding and subtracting by 2 day from the date ran

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a SQL newbie. I've created a script in SQL Developer which I then converted into Excel VBA form to build an interactive tool to pull this particular report on demand. It works great!

My issue now is I'm not able to filter the date results to show only dates 2 days before, the actual date and finally, 2 days after the actual date the report was ran.

SQL Code:

```
Select p.prdord PO, q.actdat,P.itmcod Finished_Item, p.SPCCD1 Feeder_Item,
       p.expqty Qty_Needed, p.PENDQTY Amount_Pulled, p.actqty Still_needed
from PORECIPE p join
     prdque q
     on p.prdord = q.prdord 
order by p.prdord
```

Comment: Are you talking about filtering on the VBA side (which seems like a bad idea), or passing in a date (whether it's today or something else) from VBA, or simply using `sysdate` on the DB side? (In which case, VBA doesn't seem to be relevant.)

Answer (score 0):

This code is Oracle-based filtering for the current day +- 2 days:

```
SELECT 
  p.prdord PO, 
  q.actdat,
  p.itmcod Finished_Item, 
  p.spccd1 Feeder_Item,
  p.expqty Qty_Needed, 
  p.pendqty Amount_Pulled, 
  p.actqty Still_needed

FROM 
  porecipe p 
  INNER JOIN prdque q on p.prdord = q.prdord
WHERE
  q.actdat BETWEEN SYSDATE-2 AND SYSDATE+2

ORDER BY p.prdord
```

It assumes actdat is your "actual date" column. If it isn't, sub in a different column name into the WHERE clause. Bear in mind that BETWEEN is inclusive, so if this report is run at exactly 6pm on the 3rd of Jan it will include all records from 6pm on the 1st to 6pm on the 5th. If a record at e.g. 6pm on the 5th is NOT supposed to be included, use e.g. `q.actdat > SYSDATE-2 AND q.actdat < SYSDATE+2` instead

Edit

You asked to remove weekend days, add this to the where clause:

```
AND TRUNC (q.actdat) - TRUNC (q.aftdat, 'IW') < 5
```

This will literally remove any results where q.actdat is s Saturday or Sunday

If however you mean you want results between 2 business days back and 2 business days forward it's a bit more involved- comment if so

Comment: Brilliant Sir! That's the precis solution I needed. Thank You!

Comment: To go a step further, is there a way remove the weekend days (Sat & Sun) from the results?